# How to create text area with 3 Line and scrollbar visible in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textarea, scrollbar

Scrollbar hide/show not working plus height is not managed.

Tried below code

```
Scrollbar(
controller: _scrollController,
isAlwaysShown: true,
child: TextField(
scrollController: _scrollController,
autofocus: true,
keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
maxLines: 3,
autocorrect: true,
onChanged: (s) => {},
decoration: InputDecoration(
  border: InputBorder.none,
  isDense: true,
),
 ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you input text that exceeds 3 lines, the scrollbar will appear.

isAlwaysShown is deprecated. There is no need for Scrollbar.

Comment: we are using flutter version 2.2.3 , it's deprecated in 2.9.0+